# install multiple packages from my .emacs file

Tags: package, init-file

I share my .emacs file between machines, which works great but I use a lot of packages and when emacs starts on a new machine with the .emacs it complains about the missing package.  I can ignore it until I install that package, but it's laborious having to manually install packages.  Is there a way to install all the packages needed by my .emacs file?

Answer (score 1):

I manage this by dotting `require-package` calls around [my emacs config](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/), where `require-package` is defined as follows:

```
(defun require-package (package &optional min-version no-refresh)
  "Install given PACKAGE, optionally requiring MIN-VERSION.
If NO-REFRESH is non-nil, the available package lists will not be
re-downloaded in order to locate PACKAGE."
  (if (package-installed-p package min-version)
      t
    (if (or (assoc package package-archive-contents) no-refresh)
        (package-install package)
      (progn
        (package-refresh-contents)
        (require-package package min-version t)))))
```

and then elsewhere I'll have code like:

```
(require-package 'haskell-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'interactive-haskell-mode)
```

If you want to get fancier about it, you can use John Wiegley's [use-package](http://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package, which has an `:ensure` keyword that triggers package installation. But then, you still have to install `use-package` itself first, e.g. with a call to `package-install`!

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. I took the idea from [Aaron Bedra](http://www.aaronbedra.com/emacs.d/). Basically you group the packages you want to install. If they are not installed, they will be installed when you start Emacs. If they are already installed, nothing happens.

```
(defvar custom/packages '(ido-ubiquitous
          ido-vertical-mode
          flx-ido
          smex
          browse-kill-ring
          hungry-delete
          smartscan
          org
          magit
          auctex
          latex-pretty-symbols
          ebib
          latex-preview-pane
          latex-extra
          adaptive-wrap
          clojure-mode
          cider
          pandoc-mode
          multifiles
          rainbow-delimiters
          bookmark+)
  "Default packages")

(defun custom/packages-installed-p ()
  (loop for pkg in custom/packages
        when (not (package-installed-p pkg)) do (return nil)
        finally (return t)))

(unless (custom/packages-installed-p)
  (when (not package-archive-contents)
    (message "%s" "Refreshing package database...")
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (dolist (pkg custom/packages)
      (when (not (package-installed-p pkg))
    (package-install pkg)))))
```

Comment: If you are missing packages from the list, but `package-archive-contents` is non-nil, then your `(when (not package-archive-contents) ...` form aborts prematurely, which means that the missing packages don't get installed.

Comment: Thanks for that. It never happend to me, but it is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Since I write my configuration in a org file and then use some org-babel magic to make a .el which is loaded later by Emacs, I wrote a script in Python that I run from the same org file and it creates a .el file with every package installed in my emacs configuration, this is how it looks:

```
** Repositorio de paquetes
<Spanish comments omitted...>

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (setf package-archives (list (quote ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
                               (quote ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
                               (quote ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
                               (quote ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))))
#+end_src

<Spanish comments omitted...>

** Listado, revisión e instalación de paquetes con Melpa
<Spanish comments omitted...>

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '(
     (emacs-lisp . t)
     (python . t)
     )
  )
#+END_SRC

#+name: codigopython
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :file paquetes.el
  import os

  if os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser("~/.emacs.d/elpa/")):
      melpapackages = os.listdir(os.path.expanduser("~/.emacs.d/elpa/"))
      packagestoinstall = []
      for package in melpapackages:
          if os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser("~/.emacs.d/elpa/") + package):
              name = package[:package.rfind("-")]
              if not name == "archive":
                  packagestoinstall.append(
                      "(use-package {0}\n  :ensure {0})".format(name))

      # Remove any repeated package. This can happen if different directories
      # with the same package name exists in the elpa/ directory
      packagestoinstall = list(set(packagestoinstall))

      # Sort things, please!
      packagestoinstall.sort()
      print("\n".join(packagestoinstall))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: codigopython
[[file:paquetes.el]]

<Spanish comments omitted...>

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
  (unless (file-exists-p (expand-file-name "elpa/archives/melpa" user-emacs-directory))
    (package-refresh-contents))

  (when (not (package-installed-p 'use-package))
    (package-install 'use-package))

  (require 'use-package)
  (load-file (expand-file-name "paquetes.el" user-emacs-directory))
#+END_SRC

<Spanish comments omitted...>
```

I just have to move the cursor inside the source block with the python code, do <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and BAM! I have all my packages installed listed automatically :)

If you want, you can copy the Python snippet and paste it inside a file, so you can call it as a command from your shell, redirecting the output to a file. This in case you don't use org-mode and org-babel for your Emacs configuration!